# What does the -webkit prefix before some properties in css mean?

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS in which in some properties inside CSS definition starts with -webkit prefix

For example, in the following CSS there are one properties prefixed with a -webkit for text

```
 p {
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f1c40f, #27ae60);
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       background-clip: text;
}
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix.  It targets a certain class of browser.  It's rarely used anymore since most browsers implement standards.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit is a "vendor/browser prefix" it's a way for browsers to add support for certain features before they're available as standard on all browsers, making development easier. They basically ensure that you can use brand new CSS features in development. You can read more about them in the docs. [Vendor Prefix - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

Answer (score 0):

[WebKit](https://webkit.org/) is a web browser engine used by some browsers like [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)).

[Some CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions) with the `-webkit` prefix will target only the browsers using the WebKit engine. The CSS rule with the `-webkit` prefix will only apply to browsers using the WebKit engine.

For example:

```
div{-webkit-opacity: 0.5;}
```

For users viewing the website on a WebKit-based browser, the div will have the opacity of `0.5`. For users viewing the webpage on a non-WebKit browser, the div will be fully opaque, i.e, the rule will not apply.